# How to remove rows with different values within the same option value

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL, can someone help me understand what the query may look like if I'm trying to remove the red-highlighted rows from the image? Based on the logic I need, I need to remove records with **different** priority values within an option, where as the ones we want to keep have the same priority. Each item/cntry combination has it's own option values (typically 4 like you see here).

I feel like this is just a join to itself, but my mind is mush right now. Help would be appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the analytic `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` function and then you do not need to use a self-join:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT(DISTINCT priority) OVER (PARTITION BY cntry, item, "OPTION")
           AS cnt
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  cnt = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ("OPTION", priority, item, cntry) AS
SELECT 1, 1, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'ABCDEF', 'USA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 1, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 2, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 1, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2, 'HIJKLM', 'CAN' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | OPTION | PRIORITY | ITEM | CNTRY | CNT |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | HIJKLM | CAN | 1 |
> | 3 | 1 | HIJKLM | CAN | 1 |
> | 3 | 1 | HIJKLM | CAN | 1 |
> | 3 | 1 | HIJKLM | CAN | 1 |
> | 4 | 2 | HIJKLM | CAN | 1 |
> | 1 | 1 | ABCDEF | USA | 1 |
> | 1 | 1 | ABCDEF | USA | 1 |
> | 4 | 2 | ABCDEF | USA | 1 |
> | 4 | 2 | ABCDEF | USA | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=2be5315390a4eb520937bf8f64a3f320)*

Comment: This worked perfectly. I just put cnt <> 1 to find the rows I needed to omit. Thanks a ton for the help!

Answer (score 0):

use exists and distinct count()

```
select t1.* from table_name t1 where
exists ( 
select 1
from table_name t2
where t1.option=t2.option
group by option
having count (distinct priority)=1
)
```